# How to keep first 0 in csv when open it and save as in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I created csv file in format "Surname;Birthday;Name". Where Birthday is in format ddmmyyyy (e.g. 01121989 or 09111983).

When I opened it in Excel It did not show first '0'.

1. Can I escape this symbol to show full date in Excel?
2. When I saved this file from Excel using option "Save as" It lost first '0' in Birthday. Is it possible to prevent this?

Thank you.

Comment: csv has no formatting capabilities. if you want to keep formatting, save as a REAL .xls/xlsx file.

Comment: I have requirement to save in CSV format

Comment: `01121989` is not a date format excel could automatically recognize. either produce a real .xls file and do wahtever formatting you want there, or reset your date fields to be somethign that excel DOES recognize as a date. those are you two options.

Comment: only csv. changing date format is not possible too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you open the file, right-click the column letter (e.g., `B`) and select `Format Cells`.  Then choose `Custom`, and set the format to `00000000`.  This will add the leading `0` to all cells where it is missing, and when you save it as `.csv`, it will export the leading `0` in the output file too.

Answer (score 4):

In stead of opening the csv as you normally would use a data connection.

For this go to your ribbon item Data > From Text

Browse to your CSV and select Open. Now you will get a text-to-columns window where you can set the specific column properties to Text (so not General or Number). This way the complete set of characters are available.

Comment: Yes. But When I go to save file I will lose first 0 in date.

Comment: If you format the column as Text it should not do this.  If you format it as a number, date, or general, you could lose leading zeros.

Comment: As the column should remain in Text format the formatting should stay even when you save it again. If this is not the case please specify further what you do and what happens.

Answer (score 1):

This is typical Excel. You can consider using single quotes:

```
A,'01121989',B
```

If you are using a program to read this file you can clear these single quotes easily.

Comment: Unfortunate It does not fit requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Format your date cells as Text.

Right-click, Format Cells, under *Category* select Text.

Normally, when you enter some number in Excel, you will see it aligns right, if you enter the same numbers in a Text formatted cell, it will align left, and any zeroes at the starts will be kept.

Comment: Once you have opened the file, it is too late to set the cell formatting to `Text` because the zeros have already been lost.

Comment: I'm taking into account when the data is exported: `When I saved this file from Excel using option "Save as" It lost first '0' in Birthday. Is it possible to prevent this?`